# How to view values in debugger?

Tags: xcode, debugging, swift

In Xcode 6.3, how do I view the values of objects such as:

arrary count: `myarray.count`

TableView index: `indexPath.item`

These don't show up in the debugger and I don't know how to print them out into the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the app is paused on a breakpoint, the debugger (lldb) has a few [commands](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html) available.

To (p)rint (o)ut an object, you can do:

```
po myObject.debugDescription
po myArray.count
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to `log` them to console using NSLog / println depending on which language you use.

**In Objective-C:**

```
NSLog(@"My Array Count: %i", myarray.count");
```

**In Swift:**

```
println("My Array Count: \(myarray.count)")
```

Same goes for `indexPath.item` - you can print item, row, selection or even whole content of your cell, such as textLabel's text, the same way you print number of items in an array.

---

For more advanced way of accesing number of items in your memory (such as a count of an array), you can always use Apple's `Instruments` application, and its build in `Allocations`.
From there you can track how many objects you have in your memory:

[image]

Comment: I don't want to litter the code with these statements.  I'd like access from the debugger via breakpoints...just like all other variables.

Comment: po is what I was looking for.  I think that is the only way to access the two variables above?